# Cannot connect to a specific wifi network from desktop

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I recently moved to a new apartment that has its own wifi network. I have been able to connect to the network with an android phone, a mac laptop, and a windows desktop but am unable to get my ubuntu desktop to connect. I have verified the password is correct but every time I try it just tells me to try again. The ubuntu machine can connect to my phone hotspot and my previous apartment's wifi just fine.

I have seen other issues like this around but none of their solutions have worked for me. Below are some commonly asked for outputs if any of them help diagnose the issue

**ifconfig**:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:b1:dc:75:4f  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enxa4ae1283c010: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether a4:ae:12:83:c0:10  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2305  bytes 229772 (229.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2305  bytes 229772 (229.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx9848274f5ff4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 2312
        inet 192.168.233.169  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.233.255
        inet6 fe80::6746:6398:657b:8a77  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 98:48:27:4f:5f:f4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 188716  bytes 310693734 (310.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 4210  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 85471  bytes 9446889 (9.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 4 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**sudo lshw -c network**

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc50ffff memory:fc510000-fc513fff
  *-network:0
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: wlx9848274f5ff4
       serial: 98:48:27:4f:5f:f4
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88XXau driverversion=5.8.0-55-generic ip=192.168.203.169 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:3.1
       logical name: enxa4ae1283c010
       serial: a4:ae:12:83:c0:10
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.11.11 duplex=half firmware=rtl8153b-2 v1 10/23/19 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
```

**rfkill list**

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Looks like wlx9848274f5ff4 got an IP address, what do you mean you cannot connect?

Comment: @ubfan1 When i have my computer try to connect to the specific wifi network if fails every time. But the computer can connect to other networks just fine and other computers can connect to the specific network too.